# What does "Up, Hit, Down, and over" mean in Action Script 3? How do I create "scrolling"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, action

So what do they mean?

I am making an "interactive" iPhone as a project.

Currently I have 1 scene and within it, a movie clip labeled iphone and within it, about 8 or so buttons for different "apps". I want to create a scrolling affect after clicking one of the icons. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to creating Button type symbols, as in:

[image: create-symbol]

There are four states in the timeline to skin the visual appearance of the button depending on mouse interaction.

[image: button-timeline]

- **Up** - Button's appearance when the pointer is not over the button.
- **Over** - Button's appearance when the pointer is over the button.
- **Down** - Button's appearance as it is being clicked.
- **Hit** - Defines the area bounds that will respond to a mouse click.  This area is invisible when published.

Addressing the remainder of your question, creating a virtual iPhone in Flash running various apps is substantial depending on scope.  I would recommend breaking that down in to multiple questions.